# JSP com Servlet

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou tentando fazer com que a servlet trabalhe como um controlador
estava seguindo a apostila da caelum mas não consigo encontrar o erro

o jsp
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a servlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/LoginInfo")
public class LoginInfo extends HttpServlet {
    public LoginInfo(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
        String acao = request.getParameter("acao");
        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String senha= request.getParameter("senha");
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUsuario(usuario);
        login.setSenha(senha);
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        if(acao.equals("Entrar")){
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/paginaInicial.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
```

a paginaInicial.jsp
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o erro que dá

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     br.com.vitor.controlador.LoginInfo.doPost(LoginInfo.java:41)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Essa é alinha que faz a comparação se é igual a "Entrar"

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente, é por que não existe nenhum input na página com o `name="acao"`, e por isso a variável acao está nula. No submit da página vc colocou `acao="Entrar"` e `value="Login"`, mas o que você espera no servlet é `name="acao"` e `value="Entrar"`.

Outra dica, pra evitar erros de valor nulo. Quando estiver testando strings, chame o equals da constante, não da variável. Então ao invés de `acao.equals("Entrar")` você faz `"Entrar".equals(acao)`. Assim se acao for nulo, o equals retorna falso, mas não estoura uma exceção.